# Chamar função Python que já esteja rodando

Tags: python, funções

Tenho o seguinte cenário.

Tenho uma função que consome muita RAM e gostaria de deixa-la rodando em background para cada vez que eu for chamar ela não ter que carregar novamente todos os dados em memória, e quando eu precisar do seu resultado eu realizo a chamada dela.

No caso eu preciso informar um parâmetro e ela deve me retornar um resultado, como fazer isso em Python?

Lembrando que esse que irá processar eu preciso que ele esteja rodando e quando o outro for se comunicar com ele seja só chamar esse modulo que já está rodando.

****Bom como você disse deixa eu exemplificar melhor.*****

Eu tenho um arquivo de  1,5 GB que contém varios textos e eu subo ele em memória, e realizo consulta nesses textos. O que eu não quero é que a cada consulta eu tenha que carregar esse arquivo.

Eu quero que ele fique rodando de fundo enquanto eu navego nas outras telas que eu tenho(Estou usando Django, criei varias páginas e uma dessas páginas permite eu realizar consultas nesse arquivo) pois várias telas vão usar esse arquivo de maneira diferente, então eu gostaria de ter um processo rodando sempre e quando eu precisar de um retorno eu chamo esse processo e ele retorna o que eu desejo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está praticamente descrevendo um dos conjuntos de vantagens de se usar programação orientada a objetos.

Apesar de que em Python é possível sim, ter uma "função" que fica com um estado (os dados) carregados e você consiga, de fora dela, mandar executar um trecho e receber um valor de volta, com o uso de "generators", esse não é um uso muito comum para funções.

Para objetos, no entanto, é bem natural. Infelizmente você não deu exemplo do que quer fazer. Claro que se o problema for demora do tempo para ler ou produzir os dados, ou não ter cópias repetidas dos dados, esse método ajuda. Se apenas uma cópia dos dados já te traz problemas de memória, não tem muito o que fazer.

Vamos supor que o que você precisa seja ler dados de um arquivo do Excel, e aí ter uma chamada que consulta dados que estavam nessa planilha: você pode ter uma classe que lê o arquivo no inicializador (o método `__init__`, e guarda os dados em memória, e um método que consulta uma dada célula:

```
import pandas as pd

class Planilha:
    def __init__(self, caminho_do_arquivo):
         self.dados = pd.read_excel(caminho_do_arquivo)

    def consulta(self, linha, coluna):
         return self.dados.loc[linha, coluna]
```

E você cria uma instância da classe planilha, que lê o arquivo uma vez, e a cada consulta de dados, pode chamar o método "consulta". (Esse exemplo é bem tosco, já que você poderia usar o objeto retornado por `.read_excel`, que é um pandas DataFrame diretamente, e nem precisaria da classe planilha - mas se precisar de processamento mais especializado em cima dos dados contidos na planilha, já faz sentido um design desses.

De qualquer forma, tudo o que descrevi até aqui se aplica a código que é executado para inicializar os dados - e retorna o controle pra você, mas mantém uma referência a esses dados inicializados.

Se for realmente como você descreve de esse código ter que "ficar rodando de fundo" e só responder quando for chamado (talvez com um resultado parcial?), aí é outra história - você vai precisar usar threads ou processos separados. Mas não dá pra saber sem exemplo. Pode ser que "o que fica rodando" fique melhor se for um processo "worker" acrescentando dados a um banco de dados, e você possa usar uma função normalzinha só pra consultar esse banco. O ideal é colocar em uma próxima pergunta os dados que você tem, o que você quer, e que abordagens você ja tentou, com código mesmo.

Comment: Editei a minha pergunta colocando mais detalhes

Comment: Se é o seu caso de uso, então o exemplo que eu dei, da classe é a resposta. Só em vez de ler a planilha com a chamada ao Pandas, você lê o seu arquivo de texto.

Comment: mas a solução ideal aí é colocar esses dados num banco SQL, em ve de deixar em memória: aí você não consome toda essa memória só pra agilizar o acesso aos dados. Deixe isso pra uma segunda etapa: aproveite agora pra estudar classes.